# bootstrap overlapping column how can i fix this?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5.3

I have an issue.
Text in the div col of bootstrap overlapping

[This is the problem in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eufdH.png)

[This is the code in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCjVT.png)

Thanks, Sorry for bad English

Comment: Code should be in the question, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 solutions. :

_in the css class below, the text will be cut off and end with 3 dots

```
.my-new-class{
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

_in the css class below, the word will just display in multiple lines.

```
.my-new-class{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS property to wrapping the text.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```